# Interchanging supremum and integral (another question)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, integration

Suppose that $\varphi$ is a smooth $\mathcal{K}_{\infty}$-function and $\bar{\textbf{B}}$ is the unit ball set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $x : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be such that $x(.,\xi)$ is differentiable for each $\xi$ and $x(t,.)$ is uniformly locally Lipschitz for each $t$. Also let $\omega : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\omega(0) = 0$ and $\omega(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. I'd like to know that whether the following holds
$$
\sup_{\xi \in \bar{\textbf{B}}} \int_{s=0}^{s=t}{\varphi(\omega(x(s,\xi)))ds} = \int_{s=0}^{s=t}{\sup_{\xi \in \bar{\textbf{B}}} \varphi(\omega(x(s,\xi)))ds}.
$$
In other words, are the supremum and integral signs interchangable?

Comment: What does "(another question)" in the title mean?

Comment: @joriki He asked another question with the same title.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) or the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). For a more general aproch use the following result:

> Theorem. Let $\{ F_t ; t\in T\}$ be a family of functions 
>   $F_t : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ depending on a parameter $t$; let
>   $\mathcal{B}_X$ be a topological base $X$ and $\mathcal{B}_{T}$ a topological base in $T$. If
>   the family converges uniformly on $X$ over the base $\mathcal{B}_{T}$
>   to a function $F : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and the limit
>   $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}} F_t(x)=A_t$ exists for each $t\in T$, the both
>   repeated limits $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}F_t(x))$
>   and $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}F_t(x))$ exist and
>   the equality

Proof. See [Zoric](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=XF8W9W-eyrgC&pg=PR3&dq=zorich%20Mathematical%20analysis%20II&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=dDbzTvSdNsWEtgeO3oXQBg&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=zorich%20Mathematical%20analysis%20II&f=false). P. 381.